# Can not install AHP extension in ArcGIS 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, extensions

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2 and I need to add the AHP extension to my ArcMap.
I was trying to add AHP extension to ArcGIS. However, when I want to add the dll file (extAhp 2.0) then I get this error.

This picture shows when I'm selecting extAhp.dll

[image]

Then I get this error.

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please remember to always include the exact error message as ASCII text within the body of the question. This makes it searchable and legible on all devices

Answer (score 1):

When you download the zip file from [extAhp20 - Analytic Hierarchy Process for ArcGIS](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=bb3521d775c94b28b69a10cd184b7c1f), there are two files included. One is the installation setup.exe file and the other is a ReadMeFirst.txt. I'm assuming you've installed the program correctly, however, if you read the instructions in the text file you'll see the following:

After setup is complete perform the following steps:

> 1. launch ArcGIS™
> 2. go to the Customize menu, choose **Customize Mode**
> 3. go to the Commands tab. An item AHP should appear in the Categories list box 
>          (it could take a few seconds for the whole list to show up). Click on the AHP item
> 4. then click on the AHP item in the Commands list box on the right hand side 
>          (do not release the mouse button) and move this item by dragging it somewhere onto 
>          the ArcMap™ environment, e.g. on one of the toolbars
> 5. push the Close button in the Customize window. The extension is ready for use.

The key here is to go to the Customize Mode and add the AHP command tools.
[image]

There is no need to add the .dll file.

I tested this in 10.6.1.

Comment: Thank you for the answer to my question.
But I did the way Before. I downloaded the extAhp Just from there. Then I realized it does not work. I mean there was nothing in customize ( categories) so I tried to add the dll manually ( add dll ).